# R language, how can I extract the corresponding x value of the second highest peak seen from the density curve?

Tags: r

After I used a numeric vector to draw a density plot, I need to know the peak's position on x-axis.

```
plot(density(my_vector)  #From this plot, there are two peaks, right one is more higher
y_peak <- which.max(density(my_vector)$y)  #find the maximum y value
x_peak <- density(my_vector)$x[y_peak]  #find corresponding x value
```

But how can I find the lower peak's x value? Any idea will be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wish to find the points larger than surrounding points or local maximums. One way to check if a point is a local maximum is to see if it is higher than the points around it

Here is an example of a density with 2 maximums

data:

```
set.seed(10)
b = rnorm(100)
v = rnorm(100)+2
b = c(b, v)

plot(density(b))
```

[image]

```
library(dplyr) #for lag and lead functions can also do it manually if you wish
dens = density(b)$y
z = data.frame(dens = dens, lag = lag(dens), lead = lead(dens))
which(with(z, dens>lag&dens>lead))
[1] 244 348
```

Here are the maxima:

```
density(b)$x[which(with(z, dens>lag&dens>lead))]
[1] 0.7244697 2.5298402

plot(density(b))
abline(v = density(b)$x[which(with(z, dens>lag&dens>lead))])
```

[image]

EDIT: dplyr lag and lead explained:

```
dplyr::lag(b)
```

basically changes the indexes of the vector + 1:

```
c(NA, b)[-length(c(NA, b))]

all(c(NA, b)[-length(c(NA, b))] == dplyr::lag(b),  na.rm = T)
[1] TRUE

dplyr::lead(b)
```

basically changes the indexes of the vector - 1:

```
all(c(b[-1], NA) == dplyr::lead(b),  na.rm = T)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your method to extract the 2nd maximum. And I should get the 2nd high peak corresponding x value, but at frist I also through this way and the result lets me understood I need other way.

Comment: So brillant and clear !!!   `z = data.frame(b = dens, lag = lag(dens), lead = lead(dens))`, so b is redefined? And I'm sure the colname like "lag" and "lead" is just for me to better undertand or necessary format?

Comment: @Grace G added edit about `dplyr` `lag` and `lead` functions and a way to perform the same operations in base R. As for the format it was totally arbitrary, there is no need to define a data frame at all, one can just make the lag and lead vectors (named as one pleases) and do the logical test for local maximums.

Comment: @Grace G I figured out there was a typo in my solution `z = data.frame(b = dens, lag = lag(dens), lead = lead(dens))` should be `z = data.frame(dens = dens, lag = lag(dens), lead = lead(dens))` for `which(with(z, dens>lag&dens>lead))` to work. I fixed it now.